# Document Click Event Stopped on Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an Event that is called when the document loads to make it able to click each element with the Class 'header' to expand and show more details:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    InitClick();
});
```

Here is the function:

```
function InitClick() {
    $('.header').click(function () {
        $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle();
    });
}
```

Now the issue is when the results get filtered, it will then cause that click event to stop until I re-initialise it, then it will start working again... Until the Data is filtered again or has to update.

Now my main question is, has anyone got a link to something that could assist me, I've tried putting is on a $watch but the main issue I keep having is that this is called before the filtered data is returned, causing it to initialise before the data is there.

Here is MyApp.js if it helps?

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

MyApp.controller('MyAppCtrl', function ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.Users = tJSONData;
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.pageSize = 3;
    $scope.Pages = [];

    $scope.search = '';
    $scope.Completed = '';


    $scope.getData = function () {
    return $filter('filter')($scope.Users, $scope.search ||     $scope.Completed);
    }

    $scope.numberOfPages = function () {
        return Math.ceil($scope.getData().length / $scope.pageSize);
    }

    $scope.$watch('numberOfPages()', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        var tPages = [];
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.numberOfPages(); i++) {
            tPages.push(i + 1);
        }

        if ($scope.currentPage >= $scope.numberOfPages()) {
            $scope.currentPage = $scope.numberOfPages() - 1;
        }

        if ($scope.currentPage == -1) {
            $scope.currentPage = 0;
        }
        return $scope.Pages = tPages;
    })

    $scope.updatePage = function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.Users = tJSONData
        })
    }

    $scope.limitPagination = function () {
        if ($scope.currentPage == 0) {
            return $scope.currentPage;
        } else if ($scope.currentPage == 1) {
            return $scope.currentPage - 1
        } else {
            return $scope.currentPage - 2;
        }
    }
});

MyApp.filter('startFrom', function () {
    return function (input, start) {
        start =+ start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, when you call `$(selector).click` (or any other event), it will only set up the event for the elements that were grabbed at the time of the call. If the elements are removed and replaced (as seems to be your case), the new elements won't automatically have it.

Instead of using `$(selector).click(callback)`, use `$(document).on('click', selector, callback)`

In your case, it looks like this should do the trick:

```
$(document).on('click', '.header', function () {
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle();
});
```

The difference is that this way, the event is actually bound to the `document` itself, which never changes. You then filter so it'll only trigger when you click a `.header`, but it'll apply to all of them, even those added after this bit is called.

Comment: Sadly, changing it to that stops the event from happening at all :( Thanks for trying :)

Comment: What I gave you should have done the trick. Did it throw any console errors or anything?

Comment: None, the only thing I can think is because that'd add the handlers and then when a new object is added, I don't think it would have the handlers. I'd need to figure out a way to call it each time it changes but I'm not 100% sure how to do that. As to why it stopped it from working, not a clue.

Comment: In this case, the handler is on `document`, which doesn't change, so it'll always have the handler. There must be something else going on, because this is the standard approach for event listeners on dynamically added elements.

Comment: Even if the whole thing is on an ng-repeat and the class that it works off is the one that is tried to the ng-repeat?

Comment: Yes... sorta. In general, you actually want to avoid mixing jQuery and Angular because weird things can happen. That might be what's going on in. However, the code I gave you, assuming the previous worked, this should also work. But, it's a bit tricky to tell without knowing every little thing. What is really the best solution would be to ditch jQuery entirely and have an Angular-centric solution instead, likely using `$scope` values to keep track.